# Express.Js: Get value from object that key value is string value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm curious about the proper way to get a value from an object that its key value is a string.
Data post from client side And receiving from req.body in express.Js backend side.

> From client side. eg

```
var waypoints = {lat:15,lng:16};
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:'someurl',
data: { routeId:someId,origin: origin, waypoints::waypoints, destination: finaldestination.lat+','+finaldestination.lng,}
});
```

> console.log from data received from express.js backend. eg

```
{
 routeId:'1234',
 origin:'1.123,2.234',
 'waypoints[lat]':'15',
 'waypoints[lng]':'16',
 destination:'3.123,3.234,
}
```

console.log(req.body.waypoints); //undefined

I've tried to change `waypoint` to string from client side.
eg.

```
var waypoints '';
waypoints += '15,16';
```

This method works fine, get value from `req.body.waypoints` in express.js backend.

```
{
origin:'1.123,2.234',
waypoint:'15,16',
destination:'3.123,3.234'
}
```

The question here is how exactly do I get a value from `'waypoints[lat]'` and `'waypoints[lng]'`?

Comment: Use `data: JSON.stringify({ ... })` to send JSON; that way express should parse the request body back into a full object. (I'm wondering however where the `[0]` is coming from, given that there's no array in your `data.waypoint`. And why are there two colons?)

Comment: I guess that jquery do its own stringify if you pass an object for the data, which will make an array as waypoints[0].....

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for your answer I'll try your suggestion above. `[0]` is my mistake, originally waypoint is an array adding an object by for loop. So it should be `'waypoints[lat]': and 'waypoints[lng]':` Edited to clear misunderstanding.

Comment: Try `req.body['waypoints[lat]']`

Comment: @ChrisG I've tried your suggestion, this way I can send multiple values with an array into waypoint. eg `waypoints: JSON.stringify(allwaypoints)` and get a set of lan&lng later easier. Really appreciate your help :D

Comment: @Mehdi `req.body['waypoints[lat]']` also works and straight forward to the point. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice that the keys for waypoints is a string as it uses characters which are not usually compatible with the keys of a javascript object (`[` and `]`).

Therefore to acces them you can use square bracket instead of dot notation

```js
var data = {
 routeId:'1234',
 origin:'1.123,2.234',
 'waypoints[lat]':'15',
 'waypoints[lng]':'16',
 destination:'3.123,3.234'
};

console.log(data.routeId); // this works fine
console.log(data['waypoints[lat]']) // square bracket notation needed
console.log(data.waypoints[lat]); // this assumes a property waypoints and thinks you;re trying to read a property on it stored in variable "lat" which is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is really explained and clear my misunderstood. 
Appreciate your help and time :D.